# Where did the Waluigi myth come from?

Tags: gaming-history, super-mario-64-ds

A while ago, I heard there was a myth about unlocking Waluigi as a playable character in the DS port of Super Mario 64.  I've looked around the internet for the origin but all I can find are ROM hacks.

Who came up with it? How did the myth get into circulation?

Comment: Not sure if it's legit, but cited on [Mario wiki](https://www.mariowiki.com/List_of_rumors_and_urban_legends_about_Mario#Waluigi_in_Super_Mario_64_DS) is the article [The time I fooled the world](http://www.nintendoworldreport.com/feature/28610/waluigi-we-hardly-knew-ye-the-time-i-fooled-the-world)